# controlled saving in jqgrid cell editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

that's about it

Basically what I want to do is control the cell submission with a button or any other control.

Has anyone done this?

Here's some code to help:

```
$('#users').jqGrid({
      url : base_url + 'administrator/ajaxuser',
      datatype : 'json',
      mtype : 'GET',
      colNames : ['ID', 'E-mail' , 'First Name', 'Last Name','Role' ,'Active', 'Action'],
      colModel : [
          {name: 'id', index: 'id', resizable: false},
          {name: 'email', width: 400, index : 'email', editable:true, editrules : {email:true, required:true, custom:true, custom_func:check_email_exists}},
          {name: 'firstname', index:'firstname'},
          {name:'lastname', index:'lastname'},
          {name:'role', index:'role_id', editable: true, width:180, edittype: 'select', editoptions : {value :'1:administrator;3:special;2:user'}},
          {name:'active', index:'is_active', editable: true, width:180, edittype: 'select', editoptions : {value :'0:Not Active;1:Active'}},
          {name: 'action', index: 'action'}
      ],
      cellEdit : true,
      editurl : base_url + 'administrator/ajaxuseredit',
      cellurl : base_url + 'administrator/ajaxuseredit',
      beforeSaveCell : function(id, cell, value){
          alert(cell);
      },
      pager : '#pager',
      emptyrecords: 'Nothing to display',
      rowNum : 3,
      rowList : [3, 5, 7],
      sortname : 'email',
      viewrecords : true,
      caption : 'Payments Made',
      autowidth: true,
      multiselect : true,
      loadError : function(xhr, st, err){
      }
   }).navGrid('#pager', {edit:false, add:false});

   $('#users').jqGrid('saveCell', 'Row', 'iCol');
```

Comment: you mean edit a cell locally and save all the modded cells whenever you want?

Comment: yes, as it is now it is saved whenever I leave the current cell I am editing

Comment: as a jedi I sense that you'll have to modify the plugin itself to do that. does beforeSaveCell works?

Comment: haven't tried it, but I think that's not what I am after so I guess I will just have to make do with this, o, and do u mind me asking u another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row edit instead of cell edit and look at the "Full control" demo. Then change the row edit config to make only the cell you want editable.